# Visual Studio's IntelliSense does not recognize absolute paths when importing modules

Tags: visual-studio-2019, angular9, tsconfig.json

I want to use absolute paths rather than relative paths in my Angular application so I updated my tsconfig.json file like so:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
    "@environment/*": [ "./src/environments/*" ],
    "@shared/*": [ "./src/app/shared/*" ],
}
```

So far it's working fine and I am able to use the aliases within the component or the service

```
import { environment } from '@environment/environment'; // works
```

The problem now is that Visual Studio IntelliSens suggest the relative path rather than the absolute path. See image below.

[image: Visual Studio suggestion import]

What changes I need to do so that Visual studio suggest aliases that I have set in the tsconfig file rather than relative path ?